# How to Drag indicating line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code with a dragabble img id=img1 and a drop id with div1.

I want a line to appear from the dragged portion to dropped portion when dragging.

How this effect can be  achieved?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use class while `drag` & `drop` use below code

```css
.dashed {
 border: 2px dashed #999 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
document.getElementById('div1').classList.add('dashed');
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    
    document.getElementById('div1').classList.remove('dashed');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I mean a line starting from dragged portion to dropped portion

Comment: is that possible